# How to control JPA persistence in Wicket forms?

Tags: java, wicket, jpa-2.0

I'm building an application using JPA 2.0 (Hibernate implementation), Spring, and Wicket. Everything works, but I'm concerned that my form behaviour is based around side effects.

As a first step, I'm using the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. My domain objects are fetched by a `LoadableDetachableModel` which performs `entityManager.find()` in its `load` method. In my forms, I wrap a `CompoundPropertyModel` around this model to bind the data fields.

My concern is the form submit actions. Currently my form submits pass the result of `form.getModelObject()` into a service method annotated with `@Transactional`. Because the entity inside the model is still attached to the entity manager, the `@Transactional` annotation  is sufficient to commit the changes.

This is fine, until I have multiple forms that operate on the same entity, each of which changes a subset of the fields. And yes, they may be accessed simultaneously. I've thought of a few options, but I'd like to know any ideas I've missed and recommendations on managing this for long-term maintainability:

- Fragment my entity into sub-components corresponding to the edit forms, and create a master entity linking these together into a `@OneToOne` relationship. *Causes an ugly table design, and makes it hard to change forms later.*
- Detach the entity immediately it's loaded by the `LoadableDetachableModel`, and manually merge the correct fields in the service layer. *Hard to manage lazy loading, may need specialised versions of the model for each form to ensure correct sub-entities are loaded.*
- Clone the entity into a local copy when creating the model for the form, then manually merge the correct fields in the service layer. *Requires implementation of a lot of copy constructors / clone methods.*
- Use Hibernate's `dynamicUpdate` option to only update changed fields of the entity. *Causes non-standard JPA behaviour throughout the application. Not visible in the affected code, and causes a strong tie to Hibernate implementation.*

Comment: Welcome to my nightmares ;), we encountered the same problems.. you also bump into this if you use lists / tables with inplace edit and adding new entries into the list. due to the fact that that JPA merge() returns a new copy and you might hold onto an stale object in the UI layer.. The only clean way around i think is using DTO (or JPA entities you never attach to an EM). Lots of ugly code to copy changes back and forth. I 'm looking forward for the answers here. I never got once when i asked here or on the wicket ML ..

Comment: If you're going with the cloning option, you could look into using a bean mapper like Dozer to save you writing code. Don't how it interacts with lazy loaded bean properties though.

Comment: I'm trying the Dozer approach now - it seems to be having problems with my `@ElementCollection` list field, probably due to lack of a public setter.

Comment: Multiple forms in the same page, or multiple windows? I'm not seeing a problem... What do you mean by 'simultaneously'?

Comment: @tetsuo - I mean multiple users in different sessions. For a simple example, Alice opens the contact address form while Bob opens the pricing form against the same customer. If Alice hits "Save" first, what happens to her changes when Bob hits "Save"? It's a little more complex in reality, as some of the forms are tables with in-place editing.

Comment: Is the question related to managing versioning/mid-air collisions in JPA, or how to handle the fallout from a collision in wicket?

Comment: @ireddick - the key problem is handling of edit situations that update a subset of an entity's properties. The naive implementation of JPA in Wicket changes properties outside the transaction, leading to unpredictable results.

Comment: @Adrian Cox - Wicket has no JPA implementation, or indeed any inheritent knowledge of persistence. I think you are confusing the (non-trivial) issue of interleaving concurrent updates in JPA with how to integrate this with wicket. If you take wicket out of the equestion, what is the behaviour that you expect from your service methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

The obvious solution is to lock the entity (i.e. row) when you load it for form binding. This would ensure that the lock-owning request reads/binds/writes cleanly, with no concurrent writes taking place in the background. It's not ideal, so you'd need to weigh up the potential performance issues (level of concurrent writes).

Beyond that, assuming you're happy with "last write wins" on your property sub-groups, then Hibernate's 'dynamicUpdate' would seem like the most sensible solution, unless your thinking of switching ORMs anytime soon. I find it strange that JPA seemingly doesn't offer anything that allows you to only update the dirty fields, and find it likely that it will in the future.

**Additional (my original answer)**

Orthogonal to this is how to ensure you have a transaction open when when your Model loads an entity for form binding. The concern being that the entities properties are updated at that point and outside of transaction this leaves a JPA entity in an uncertain state.

The obvious answer, as Adrian says in his comment, is to use a traditional transaction-per-request filter. This guarantees that all operations within the request occur in single transaction. It will, however, *definitely* use a DB connection on every request.

There's a more elegant solution, with code, [here](http://faler.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/building-a-more-scalable-open-session-in-view/). The technique is to lazily instantiate the entitymanager and begin the transaction only when required (i.e. when the first EntityModel.getObject() call happens). If there is a transaction open at the end of the request cycle, it is committed. The benefit of this is that there are never any wasted DB connections.

The implementation given uses the wicket RequestCycle object (note this is slightly different in v1.5 onwards), but the whole implementation is in fact fairly general, so and you could use it (for example) outwith wicket via a servlet Filter.

Comment: Now that's an interesting answer that I hadn't seen before. I'll give that a try and see how it works for me.

Comment: I've now taken a detailed look at your link, and implemented my own variant that uses Spring's `PlatformTransactionManager` to control the transaction. It works very well, and my code is much clearer.

Comment: @Adrian - could you share the code please? I'm interested to see how it interacts with @Transactional annotations.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor - I've separated the code out into a library, and I'll post it shortly. It doesn't work very well with `@Transactional` annotations, but this isn't causing me much of a problem. Almost all of my code is accessed via the Wicket request cycle or via CXF, and each of these allow me to easily intercept the end of request and commit the transaction. My service layer always extracts the entity manager through the `JpaHandle` class, and the few services that run on a timer thread manage their transactions manually.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I've come up with an answer. Thanks to @artbristol, who pointed me in the right direction.

1. I have set a rule in my architecture: DAO save methods must only be called to save detached entities. If the entity is attached, the DAO throws an `IllegalStateException`. This helped track down any code that was modifying entities outside a transaction.
2. Next, I modified my `LoadableDetachableModel` to have two variants. The classic variant, for use in read-only data views, returns the entity from JPA, which will support lazy loading. The second variant, for use in form binding, uses [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to create a local copy.
3. I have extended my base DAO to have two save variants. One saves the entire object using `merge`, and the other uses [Apache Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) to copy a list of properties.

This at least avoids repetitive code. The downsides are the requirement to configure Dozer so that it doesn't pull in the entire database by following lazy loaded references, and having yet more code that refers to properties by name, throwing away type safety.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see why is any of this necessary. In the example you gave: "Alice opens the contact address form while Bob opens the pricing form against the same customer. If Alice hits 'Save' first, what happens to her changes when Bob hits 'Save'?". The answer is that *nothing* happens to Alice's changes as long as the form that Bob submitted isn't bound to any of those fields. When Bob submits, the form model loads the entity (which now has Alice's changes). The entity is then updated with the data from Bob's form fields.

Comment: One of the key drivers is that the form updates the fields before my code within the page runs, and thus before the service layer has opportunity to `begin` a transaction. I could probably skip all this given clear evidence that it was safe and race-free for Wicket to modify the entity properties before calling `begin`, or that there were no performance problems in replacing the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` with a new `BeginTransactionInViewFilter`. Otherwise (according to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions) I'm relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: I see your concerns now re a possible race condition.