# How to use a single transaction for a Wicket / Spring page view?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, wicket

My previous question [How to wrap Wicket page rendering in a Spring / Hibernate transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140388/how-to-wrap-wicket-page-rendering-in-a-spring-hibernate-transaction) has led me to thinking about transaction demarcation in Wicket.

Whilst the example there was easily solved by moving business logic down into a Spring-managed layer, there are other places where this is not possible.

I have a generic DAO class, implemented by Hibernate, with

```
public class HibernateDAO<T> implements DAO<T> {

    protected final Class<T> entityClass;
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public T load(Serializable id) {
        return (T) getSession().get(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdate(T object) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
    }

}
```

and a generic model to fetch it

```
public class DAOEntityModel<T> extends LoadableDetachableModel<T>{

    private DAO<T> dao;
    private final Serializable id;

    public DAOEntityModel(DAO<T> dao, Serializable id) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public <U extends Entity> DAOEntityModel(DAO<T> dao, U entity) {
        this(dao, entity.getId());
    }

    public Serializable getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    protected T load() {
        return dao.load(id);
    }

}
```

Now I have a minimal form that changes an entity

```
public class ScreenDetailsPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean(name="screenDAO") private DAO<Screen> dao;

    public ScreenDetailsPanel(String panelId, Long screenId) {
        super(panelId);
        final IModel<Screen> screenModel = new DAOEntityModel<Screen>(dao, screenId);
        Form<Screen> form = new Form<Screen>("form") {
            @Override protected void onSubmit() {
                Screen screen = screenModel.getObject();
                dao.saveOrUpdate(screen);
            }};
        form.add(
            new TextField<String>("name", new PropertyModel<String>(screenModel, "name")));
        add(form);
    }    
}
```

So far so good - thanks for sticking with it!

So my issue is this - when the form is submitted, the PropertyModel will load the screenModel, which will happen in the transaction delineated by the @Transactional dao.load(id). The commit of the changes will when the (different) transaction started for dao.saveOrUpdate(object) is committed. In between these times all bets are off, so that the object may no longer exist in the DB to be committed.

I'm never entirely sure with DB code and transactions. Should I just shrug this off as unlikely, although I could construct other more complicated but more dangerous scenarios? If not I can't see how to demarcate the whole page logic in a single transaction, which is what my instinct tells me I should be aiming for.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350218/how-to-control-jpa-persistence-in-wicket-forms

Comment: Thanks for that link - I don't think it is a duplicate _question_, although it looks like your answer may be the _solution_.

Comment: fair comment. The question I linked to is actually way too broad. I'll add an answer to this one with an overview of the solution.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you did. I'm thinking that their should be a solution where a transaction is _created_ by the first entering of a @Transactional method, but only committed by the OSIV... I wonder how this works in PHP and Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not yet implemented it, but I'm pretty sure that @ireddick solution in [How to control JPA persistence in Wicket forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350218/how-to-control-jpa-persistence-in-wicket-forms) of lazily starting a tx in in the Wicket request cycle is the best solution here. I'm going to accept this proxy for it to stop Stack Overflow nagging me to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would solve this by putting the `@Transactional` annotation on a service-level class, used by your front-end layer code, which wraps around the DAO operations - so that the load and save happens within the same transaction. In other words, you can solve this by creating a layer of code between the form and the DAO code, a "service layer", which provides the business-level logic and hides the presence of DAOs from the presentation layer.

Comment: That's the thing, Wicket encourages these little models that distribute the logic nicely, but make it hard to wrap their invocation in a single tx. I'm trying to find out if there are Wicket solutions to this problem, or if it just isn't really a problem.

Comment: @Duncan McGregor: @Transactional on the method that is updateing / alting objects in the DB is enough and fine. Off course, there is a chance that the object no longer exists or has been updated. This is even more likely in web apps. depending on your access layer you would get an exception (like optimisticlockexception in JPA) and its up to your service / UI layer to cope with it.

Comment: I suppose that if I could not have to deal with such an error because of properly delineated transactions I'd be happier.